# How to create exact same thing in Ms Access?

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula

First of all i'm new to Ms Access, i have created small database of School, with students fee details in one excel sheet and the Fee Bill print template in other sheet, and linked them both so that i can print Fee Bill of each student. But at the end of each month i want to carried forward the fee details and remaining fee of each student, i have done it in excel also, but it got corrupted easily, and if i have to delete one student then i have to go through many things, So i want to create the same thing in access, i'm attaching the excel sheet for full explanation.

[Excel Worksheet sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_bygxUDiGLTcm5ha3RRbzgwVTg/view?usp=sharing)

Things i wanna do..

1. I want to create the same data base as the excel.
2. I want to create a template for printing fee bill for each student.
3. After every month next fee bills should be ready.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Browse for a tutorial. Have in mind please, that SO is a code helping forum, not an application writing forum.

Comment: I need a guide please , i have tried google but could not find...

Comment: First hit of a google search for "*access tutorial*": https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2013-and-2016-videos-and-tutorials-a4bd10ea-d5f4-40c5-8b37-d254561f8bce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you really need to learn a bit of access first and foremost your question is extremely broad and difficult to answer, many things would go into such a task. the below should get you started.

You should first import the data you have into Access, this will give you somewhere to start with number 1.

look into a tutorial on how to produce reports in Access this will resolve number 2

look into a tutorial on how to produce forms in Access this will allow for easier input and progress towards your 3rd objective.

Hope this helps.